# how to make SrcollLeft autosliding gallery

Tags: jquery

i m new to jquery..i want to make an scrollLeft sliding gallery..i have done the following bit..bt it slides only once..its not sliding continuously...also i wanted to highlighted the current slide which is sliding..how can i do it..can anyone help me out please??

```
$(function(){
    var $thumbs= $('div.thumbs_wrapper');
    var scrollWidth= $('ul.thumbs li').width();
    var $single_Item=$('ul.thumbs li:first');

    singleWidth= $single_Item.outerWidth(); 
    scrollRight = singleWidth;      

    setInterval(function(){
        sliding();
    }, 1000);

});

function sliding(n){
    var $thumbs= $('div.thumbs_wrapper');
    var scrollWidth= $('ul.thumbs li').width();
    $thumbs.animate({'scrollLeft':'+=' + singleWidth}, 'slow').scrollLeft(scrollWidth-scrollRight);
    $('thumbs li a').each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        if($(this).hasClass('imgage'+integer)){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
```

this is my html code

```
<div class=gallery_outer>
    <div class="gallery_inner">
        <ul class="full_img">
            <li><img src="fullSize_image/1.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="fullSize_image/2.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="fullSize_image/3.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="fullSize_image/4.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="fullSize_image/5.jpg"/></li>
            <li><img src="fullSize_image/6.jpg"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="thumbs_wrapper">        
        <ul class="thumbs">
            <li><img src="thumbnails/1.jpg" class="image1"/></li>
            <li><img src="thumbnails/2.jpg" class="image2"/></li>
            <li><img src="thumbnails/3.jpg" class="image3"/></li>
            <li><img src="thumbnails/4.jpg" class="image4"/></li>
            <li><img src="thumbnails/5.jpg" class="image5"/></li>
            <li><img src="thumbnails/6.jpg" class="image6"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my css code

```
.gallery_outer{
    margin:15px;
    width:390px;
    height:430px;
    border:5px solid #aaa;
    border-radius:10px;
    webkit-border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 5px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px 3px;
    webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px 3px;

}
.gallery_inner{

}
.full_img{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    height:282px;
    width:17296px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*left:-384px;*/
}
.full_img li{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0 !important;
    padding:9px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    width:376px;
    height:282px;
}
.full_img li img{
    width:376px;
}
.thumbs_wrapper{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:108px;
    width:324px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
}
.thumbs{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    /*width:5336px;*/
    width:668px;
    /*left:-108px;*/
}
.thumbs li{
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0 !important;
    padding:9px 8px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.thumbs li img{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.active{
    border:5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your css rules as well?

Comment: daedalus - i have added my css coding

Comment: mkoryak - i dont knw to how to add images to the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is the closest I was able to come](http://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/tYW8a/), I don't know about what you had going with the active bit, it didn't make much sense, so I didn't include it.  If you could explain what your idea was, I could try to modify my answer to suit your needs.

Comment: i want images to animate continously..in my code it stop animating after it scrolling through all the images..but i want it to animate continously..

Comment: oh yes,,thx a lot..now i want to animate full_img and thumbs image together as well as i wanted to highlight the thumbs images while each image animate..thx in advance

Comment: can i ask u 1 question..u knw u add ..innerWidth..what doesInnerwidth do..i didnt get it

Comment: @shimulsurma It gets the width of the div containing the images, so it knows how far it needs to scroll before resetting.